# How to allow customer to sell their products [Magento]

Tags: magento-1.9, php, marketplace

i have created marketplace and allow user to upload their products and allow others to buy them .

then i made list of orders (made by buyers customer ) for each product that customer partner has uploaded

i want buyers to buy product from customer and the money transfer to customer not to admin

i want to allow any transaction without admin intervention , how can i do this transaction ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use any marketplace api like Paypal adaptive , stripe marketplace api , braintree marketplace api , wepay marketplace api for that .

https://stripe.com/connect

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplace-split-payments/
https://www.braintreepayments.com/products-and-features/marketplace

If you are using any standard module for multi vendor functionality like https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace.html then it will be easy to use inbuilt solution like 
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/marketplace-stripe-payment-gateway.html

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/marketplace-paypal-adaptive-payment.html

​I hope i have clear all your doubts still have any issue please comment

**PS - we are not self promoting our plugin or product , as user asked the questions specifically about marketplace product thats why i have added extension link with api link as well**

Answer (score 0):

To allow transactions without admin intervention, you need to integrate a payment gateway that supports direct payments to the customer's account. This will enable buyers to pay the customer directly for their products without the need for admin intervention.

You can consider integrating payment gateways like PayPal, Stripe, or Square that support direct payments to the seller's account. These payment gateways have APIs that you can integrate with your marketplace to enable seamless transactions: https://marketplace.magento.com/magenest-module-stripe-global.html

Once the payment is made, you can update the order status and notify the customer and the seller about the transaction. You can also set up a commission system to automatically deduct your commission from the seller's payment before transferring the remaining amount to their account.

It's essential to ensure that your payment gateway integration is secure and complies with relevant regulations to protect your customers' payment information.